# Twilio Client - Answering machine detection

Tags: ios, twilio

I am developing an iOS application with Twilio. We have used TWIML on the server side. I read in one of the threads that Answering machine detection is not possible when using  verb. Can i have the server code using twilio rest apis? if yes, please provide some sample code.

The voice url is not called when the call is connected. It calls when the call is ringing.

Whats the best way to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

There is now [enhanced Answering Machine Detection](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/03/introducing-new-answering-machine-detection.html).

For example, the `MachineDetection` parameter can be `Enable` or `DetectMessageEnd`. `Enable` returns results as soon as recognition is complete. `DetectMessageEnd` will wait until after a greeting to return results if an answering machine is detected.

Using new AMD would look like this as seen [in the docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/answering-machine-detection):

```
curl 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX123456789/Calls.json' -X POST \
--data-urlencode 'To=+1562300000' \
--data-urlencode 'From=+18180000000' \
--data-urlencode 'MachineDetection=Enable' \
--data-urlencode 'Url=https://handler.twilio.com/twiml/EH8ccdbd7f0b8fe34357da8ce87ebe5a16' \
-u ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX123456789:[AuthToken]
```

Answer (score -1):

Twilio evangelist here.

To configure an outgoing call to use AMD, you add the *[ifMachine](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#handling-outcomes-answering-machines)* parameter to your API request.  Here is some more information about AMD:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#post-parameters-optional

Hope that helps.